# is it possible to retain data within a model class

Tags: swift

I'm new to and starting to look at swift.

is it possible to store and retrieve data in swift without having to use NSObject?

here I what I'm trying to achieve. I have a set of 4 ViewControllers.
On the first ViewController I want to record a name.
In my last ViewController I want to read that name. 
I tried to store it in a simple model as shown:

```
class infoModel
{
    var m_name : String

    init(_name: String) {
        self.m_name = _name
    }


    func getName() -> String {
        return m_name
    }
}
```

when I call getName from my fourth View its null?

I know its possible to pass data in segue or use NSUserDefaults, but I'm curious if its possible for the model object to retain the value?

Thank you in advance for your time

Comment: I assume an instance of infoModel is shared across views.  One thing to consider is that the view controllers or the underlying views may not be retained and thus your reference to infoModel is lost.  The `prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)` method allows you to pass along data as you move from controller to controller.  iOS is based on a variety of patterns, some recognizable, some arcane, that I just adopt whether I understand the underlying motivation or not.

Comment: BTW - your class is not very good Swift. That whole class should be rewritten as `struct InfoModel { let name: String }`. That's it.

Comment: That's not a *simple model*. This is a simple model: `struct InfoModel { let name : String }`. It provides the `init` method and the getter

Comment: @rmaddy Great minds think alike 

Comment: yes I'm just started to learn swift, so I know its bad :) so passing it through all the segue to the end is the only way?

Comment: @maddy+vadian - Thank you for the correction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is general programming rule for objected oriented languages.

As long as you have **reference** to the same object, you will have the object with the same data. And its up to you how you pass this data between other objects; using delegates or just assigning some variable, etc.

Also there are ways how to *save* data which allows you to save data somewhere else and then retrieve them. To saving small amount of data you can use in Swift `UserDefaults`, but for bigger amount of data you should work with some database (e.g. Realm, CoreData).